# iPhone Remote app and Apple TV

Tags: appletv

I have my Remote app set up on my iPhone to work with my Apple TV.  This was easy because my Apple TV is linked with my Apple ID Account (which is obviously identified with both my phone and my computer).  When I went to set my wife's Remote app up on her iPhone, I get a message that says "Turn on Home Sharing in iTunes on your computer or on Apple TV using the account [Name of Wife's Account]."

On the Apple TV, Home Sharing is on and I still get this message.

My wife does not have an Apple computer.  Only an iPad.  She does not use iTunes at all.

How does this work if she does not use iTunes?

Apple TV has Home sharing turned on and when I go into the Remote app on her phone and go into settings, it says Home Sharing is turned on.

I just want to link her phone up.  How do I do this and why do I have to?  Shouldn't there just be a way to use her phone as a remote without making it a part of my Home Sharing network?

Answer (score 1):

Is home sharing activated for the same account? (If she uses a different apple ID, then the two devices won't bind).

In that case, pair the remote via the apple tv's settings (under general i believe)